# Make reported an error "There are no rules to create 'mykernel. bin', stop"

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

system:ubuntu22.10
I'm trying to make mykernel.bin
However, an error was reported. See the title for details
This is my makefile code:

```
GPPPARAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fleading-underscore -fno-exceptions -fno-builtin -nostdlib -fno-rtti

ASPARAMS = --32

LDPARAMS = -melf_i386

objects = loader.o kernel.o

%.o: %.cpp

    g++ ${GPPPARAMS} -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.s

    as ${ASPARAMS} -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld ${objects}

    ld ${LDPARAMS} -T $< -o $@ ${objects}

install: mykernel.bin

    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

I tried to modify the makefile because I just learned it and it didn't have much effect
I hope someone can help me solve the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: I can't repro. If I `touch linker.ld loader.o kernel.o` and then run `make`, it proceeds to run `ld -melf_i386 -T linker.ld -o mykernel.bin loader.o kernel.o`

Comment: (Using curlies around the `make` variables is slightly unusual; the normal standard syntax would be `${objects)` etc.)